# DropDownList with Textbox Input as filter criteria

Tags: c#, javascript, html, asp.net-mvc

I need to have a `DropDownList` or equivalent in *ASP.NET MVC* in a View, which is populated with a bunch of entries from a database.

When selected, the `DropDownList` should produce the List as usual, with the exception that the user can enter text into it, at which point the items in the `DropDownList` will be filtered based on the entered text.

The user should however still only be able to choose one of the options in the list.

It could be any other control, but preferably NOT a 3rd party thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a decent method that works.

The only problem with this is that it requires 2 separate controls (`DropDownList` and `TextBox`), but other than that, works beautifully.

HTML Code (declaration of controls) is:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <div>
                <%: Html.Label("Search Filter:")%>
            </div>
        </td>
        <td>
            <div>
                <%: Html.TextBox("textBoxForFilterInput")%>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <div>
                <%: Html.Label("The List")%>
            </div>
        </td>
        <td>
            <div>
                <%: Html.DropDownList("listOfOptions")%>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

The JavaScript code is:

```
    $(function () {
        var opts = $('#listOfOptions option').map(function () {
            return [[this.value, $(this).text()]];
        });

        $('#textBoxForFilterInput').keyup(function () {
            var rxp = new RegExp($('#textBoxForFilterInput').val(), 'i');
            var optlist = $('#listOfOptions').empty();
            opts.each(function () {
                if (rxp.test(this[1])) {
                    optlist.append($('<option/>').attr('value', this[0]).text(this[1]));
                }
            });
        });
    });
```

Then just populate `#listOfOptions` and then you should be good to go.

Alternatively, you could hook it up to a predefined list/array or fetch it from a database like I do.

This works like a charm, very simple and super fast.

Thanks to [DMI](https://stackoverflow.com/users/122017/dmi) for sending me on the right path.

His work on this can be found [here](http://jsfiddle.net/VeLKW/2/).

Answer (score 1):

It is possible by writing some jQuery code. But it is already available and it is open source, widely used

Use [jQuery chosen](http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/) and configure like below

```
 $(".select").chosen();
```

Comment: I cannot get this to work. I included the file and the method .chosen even pops up with the intellisense, but I keep getting an error:

object doesn't support this property or method 'chosen'

Answer (score 0):

For this .autoComplete of Jquery can be used.

HTML is like

`<table><tr><td><input type="textbox" id="textBoxid" />                                  <div id="targetDiv" style="z-index:10"></div>`

Jquery code will be like

```
 $(function () {
        $("#textBoxid").autocomplete({
            appendTo: "#targetDiv",
            position: { at: "bottom bottom" },
            source: function (request, response) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: '@Url.Action("ActionMethod", "Controller")',
                    type: "POST",
                    dataType: "json",
                    data: { searchString: request.term },
                    success: function (data) {
                        response($.map(data, function (item) {
                            return { label: item.ColumnValue, Id:item.ColumnId }
                        }))
                    }
                })
            },
            select: function (event, ui) {
                if (ui.item) {
 // for saving the selected item id or any other function you wanna perform on selection
                    $('#hiddenfield').val($.trim(ui.item.Id));
                }
            }
        });
```

Action Method will be like

```
        [HttpPost]
        public JsonResult MaterialDesc(string searchString)
        {
```

// On searchString basis you can have your code to fetch data from database.
            }

hope it can help you 
:)